# Unable to load misty package in R

Tags: r, package, load

Was able to install the misty package but got an error when loading the package.

Tried reinstalling but got the same error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘misty’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/misty/libs/misty.so':
```

```
Reason: tried: '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Comment: Already tried `brew install gcc`?

Comment: Yes have tried this, after installation, I restarted R, and tried loading the package but got the same error.

Comment: Check `gcc --version` if it's correctly installed, then what gives `which gcc`?

Comment: Here is what I got when checking gcc --- version: 
```Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin```

And which gcc: ```/usr/bin/gcc```